# how to configure entrust SSL certificate with Heroku SSL

Tags: ssl, heroku, openssl, ssl-certificate, heroku-toolbelt

Hi I not bale to configure my entrust SSL certificate with Heroku
I download my certificate from entrust with below option

```
Select Certificate: my domain name
Select Server Type: Other
```

its give me three file for download 
1)L1Cchain.txt
2)L1Croot.txt
3)entrustcert.crt

after that I fellow steps :

step 1) create private key using.

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out server.pass.key 2048 with password "passone"
openssl rsa -in server.pass.key -out server.key with password "passone"
```

step 2) bundle all certificate in one file called server.pem.

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- 
L1Cchain.txt
-----END CERTIFICATE----- 
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- 
L1Croot.txt
-----END CERTIFICATE----- 
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- 
entrustcert.crt
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

step 3) heroku certs:add server.pem server.key -a myapp

when I am at step 3 I got error

```
heroku certs:add server.pem server.key -a myapp
Resolving trust chain... failed
 !    No key found that signs the certificate.
```

with option bypass

```
heroku certs:add heroku.pem server.key  -a myapp --bypass
Adding SSL Endpoint to myapp... failed
 !    Key doesn't match the PEM certificate
```

please help me to solve this problem and what I am miss out to configure.
I am using windows PC and my heroku toolbelt

```
heroku --version
heroku/toolbelt/3.4.1 (i386-mingw32) ruby/1.9.3
```

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are bundling your chain in the wrong order. enTrust NGINX instructions (recommended by Heroku) says to bundle them in this order.

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
(Your Web server Certificate) // entrustcrt.crt
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
(Entrust L1C Cross Certificate) // L1Cchain.txt
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
(Entrust 2048 Root) // L1Croot.txt
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

After that, I got it working using...

```
heroku certs:add server.pem server.key -a myapp --bypass
```